# I am using google-api-php-client for inserting data at pull queue , but i am facing an error

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-client

I am using google-api-php-client for inserting data at  pull queue , but i am facing an error

> Error : Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'google\appengine\runtime\CurlLiteOptionNotSupportedException' with
>   message 'Option 20056 is not supported by this curl implementation.'
>   in
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/CurlLite.php:487
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/CurlLite.php(215):
>   google\appengine\runtime\CurlLite->setOption(20056, NULL) #1
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/CurlLiteStub.php(1325):
>   google\appengine\runtime\CurlLite->setOptionsArray(Array) #2
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/CurlLiteStub.php(1319):
>   curl_setopt_array(Object(google\appengine\runtime\CurlLite), Array) #3
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~apigraymatics/1.390228445902450541/public/pull/google-api-php-client/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(77):
>   curl_setopt(Object(google\appengine\runtime\CurlLite), 20056, NULL) #4
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~apigraymatics/1.390228445902450541/public/pull/google-api-php-client/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/sr
>   in
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/CurlLite.php
>   on line 487

My code is :

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';



$credentials_file = "file.json";
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/taskqueue']);
$client->setAuthConfig($credentials_file);  // This is your service account JSON key you need to export from the Developers Console
$project ='s~<project-name>';
$taskqueue ='<task-queue-name>';

$optParams = array();
$service = new Google_Service_Taskqueue($client);
$updated = new Google_Service_Taskqueue_Task($client);
$updated->getPayloadBase64('aGVsbG8=');
//$params = array('project' => $project, 'taskqueue' => $taskqueue, 'postBody' => $postBody);
$results = $service->tasks->insert($project,$taskqueue,$updated);
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Are you running this on the dev server or in production and on what OS? This bears some resemblance to https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/640. You could try testing with google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite disabled in your php.ini as per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini.

Comment: google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"  , so curl_lite is enable .... So why CurlLiteOptionNotSupportedException error occurred ???

Comment: No, that is the problem. You want to test without cURL Lite, because it doesn't support every operation that the full cURL library does. The exception means the operation isn't supported by cURL Lite, not that it isn't enabled.

Comment: did you managed to solve this, i am getting same issue